# Laravel relationship confusion

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I need help with relationships in Laravel 5.3.

I have 3 tables:
groups (group_id, group_name)
businesses (business_id, business_name)
payments (payment_id, date)

A group can have many businesses, in the model I created belongsToBusiness

A business can belong to many groups, in the model I created belongsToGroup

I've created a pivot table: business_group (business_id, group_id)

A payment belongs to one group and one business.

When the user views a group I need to display the payments for group with the business name for each payment.

When the user views a business I need to display the payments for business with the group name.

At this point I got dazed and confused.

Which relationship do I use for the payments?

Is it one of these?
Has Many Through, Polymorphic Relations, Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

If so, which one?

Someone suggested I add an id field to the business_group pivot table and then a field business_group_id field to the payments table. How do I set up the relationship in the models if I do that?

And how do I retrieve the data to display the payments?

Can someone please help?

Comment: If your payment has one group and one business, you should update the *payments* table like this - payment_id, business_id, group_id, date. Then in your payment model it should belongTo(business) and belongTo(group). In your business model it should hasMany(payments) to get all payments of this business.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, but the suggestion to add the id to the pivot table was given to me to avoid data duplication. But I think, I'll go the way you suggested.